# Blazor server scoped service is different

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to store the authenticated user `Session Id`, where access token is retrieved from dictionary per user session.

I have simple **Scoped** service `services.AddScoped<SessionService>();`

```
public class SessionService
{
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

In `MainLayout.razor` I'm injecting it and setting it when the user log in. Which works fine.

```
@inject SessionService SessionService

.....

@code {
  [CascadingParameter]
  private Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() 
  {
      SessionService.SessionId = (await AuthenticationStateTask).User.GetSessionId();
  }
}
```

However, I'm creating `HttpClient` from `IHttpClientFactory` and getting the access token based on the user `Session Id`, but all 3 different approaches to get the `SessionService` have `SessionId` set to **null**

```
services.AddHttpClient("backend", async (provider, client) =>
        {
            var httpContextAccessor = provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var httpContextService = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<SessionService>();
            using var scope = provider.CreateScope();
            var anotherProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var anotherSession = anotherProvider.GetService<SessionService>();
            var sessionId = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SessionService>()?.SessionId;
            client.BaseAddress = ...;
        });
```

If I use the service inside component the `SessionId` is what it has to be and not null. Why is that happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Probably because you're creating your client before your session actually exists. Creating the services is one of the first things that is done se your session will be null at this point. Could you not just inject the SessionService into your HttpClient class?